# Draw-method draws different lines on iOS and Android

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monogame

I am developing a game in Xamarin and are using Monogame. With the exact same code I get two different results when I play the game on Android and iOS. Here is a picture to compare the two:

[image]

The upper line is from iOS and the one under it is from Android. Do anyone know why we get two so different results when we draw the lines with the exact same code? I got a Line class which draws a line, the draw method in the line class is below.

```
public void Draw (SpriteBatch spritebatch)
{
    float angle = (float)Math.Atan2 (PointB.Y - PointA.Y,
                                     PointB.X - PointA.X);

    int length = (int)Vector2.Distance (PointA, PointB);

    LineRect = new Rectangle ((int)PointA.X, 
                              (int)PointA.Y,
                              (int)Texture.Width,
                              (int)Texture.Height);

    spritebatch.Draw (Texture,
                      PointA, 
                      LineRect, 
                      Color, 
                      angle, 
                      Vector2.Zero,
                      new Vector2 (length, Width), 
                      SpriteEffects.None, 
                      0);
}
```

If i change the `Texture.Width=1` and `Texture.Height=2` and `width` of the line to 3, it works perfectly on both Android and iOS.

But if i want to have a thicker line, and the `Texture.Width` and `Texture.Height` is 3 and the width of the line is 12, it works like a charm on Android, but then it gets buggy on iOS.

`Texture.Width=2` and `Texture.Height = 1` and `Width = 13` works on iOS.

So the question is how come something like different Texture.Height, Texture.Width and Width values can bug the line? And doesn't give the same output on iOS and Android when its just XNA?

Comment: This is obviously a bug in MonoGame. You should report it on their github issues.